# nil method error on omniauth.auth

Tags: ruby, omniauth

```
    def create
   5      debugger
   6      auth=request.env["omniauth.auth"]
=> 7      user=Moviegoer.find_by_provider_and_uid(auth["provider"],auth["uid"]) ||
   8        Moviegoer.create_with_omniauth(auth)
   9      session[:user_id] = user.id
   10      redirect_to movies_path
```

The above code is from the controller action (create) - i ran with debugger on;
I am getting 'nil' value for auth variable - i had omniauth in gem file and bundle installed it...still not able to get the above statement executed right...am i missing something here...?
***------***

I tried few things and progressed few steps -but still stuck at an error

Started GET "/auth/twitter" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-28 17:38:26 -0800

Timeout::Error (execution expired):

The code in application controller is :

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_current_user
  protected # prevents method from being invoked by a route
  def set_current_user
    debugger
    # we exploit the fact that find_by_id(nil) returns nil
    @current_user ||= Moviegoer.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
    redirect_to '/auth/twitter' and return unless @current_user
  end
end
```

I believe the code is timing out at redirect_to statement...

Comment: Are you positive the user actually authenticated?

Comment: There is nothing to do with both `omniauth` and `Moviegoer`. You state the problem clearly: your request has no `omniauth.auth` set. So, examine your request to see whether it does not supply the auth and why.

Answer (score 0):

You should map your oauth callback to your **create** action.

```
# config/routes.rb
match '/auth/:provider/callback' => 'authentications#create'
```

Comment: If you directly make a `GET` request on `/auth/twitter`, you still get a `Timeout::Error`? You may check if you right configured `omniauth` and set the valid Twitter key/secret.

Comment: omniauth.rb (config)

SETUP_PROC = lambda do |env|
  env['omniauth.strategy'].options[:consumer_key] = ENV['TWITTER_KEY']
  env['omniauth.strategy'].options[:consumer_secret] = ENV['TWITTER_SECRET']
end

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :twitter, setup: SETUP_PROC
end                                                                              environment variables are assigned in environment.rb